# Can we define a nonclustered index without defining the clustered index?

Tags: database, database-design

Can we define a nonclustered index without defining the clustered index on a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can.

In this case, the `RID`s will serve instead of the clustered keys as record pointers.